# Sorting English Style dates

Tags: sorting, date, excel, vba

I have a macro which is sorting a group of columns in an ascending order using column A which has an English format date and time in it. Each selection of data in the sheet covers two days. That's fine and working OK until the month changes at which point 30/04/2014 is treated as a larger value than 01/05/2014. At that point the 01/05/2014 rows are put to the top and the 30/04/2014 are sorted to the bottom, the opposite of what i would want.

Here's the snippet of code that does the sorting.

```
With Range("AA1")
        .Value = 1
        .Copy

        'Modified the value conversion section to avoid changing the date to an american format

        With Range("B1:Z" & WriteToRow - 1)
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlMultiply
        End With
        With Range("A1:Z" & WriteToRow - 1)
            .Sort key1:=Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With

        .Value = ""
```

Can anyone help with this? I have thought that i could add an **IF statement** to say if the first 2 characters of A2 are 01 then sort descending but then i would need another IF to say that if the first two characters are 02 sort **again** into ascending so that when the file is processing between the 1st and 2nd of each month the order is correct. It seemed a bit messy to me so i thought i'd see if someone much smarter than me had a cleaner solution.

Thanks, 7's

Comment: if sorting goes like this. these are not dates but strings looking like dates, try using DATEVALUE() on them

Comment: Doh that's so simple as well! Can't beleive i didn't see that! Thanks for the fresh look.

Comment: Yep if they're *all* english-style dates, then you can use `=DateValue(Text(A1,"DD-MM-YYYY"))`.  One thing to be careful with these is that sometimes Excel tries to be smarter than the user, it interprets English dates (01/05/2014 -- May 1) as an American date (January 5).

Comment: @DavidZemens Excel's interpretation is dependent on the user's system locale as specified in Control Panel.

Comment: @Cor_Blimey yes, that is the problem, because a value like "01/05/2014" is a *valid* date in either UK or US locale, but could be interpreted differently depending on that setting for example when importing from text, etc.  If the dates are keyed in under UK locale, saved, and then re-opened in US locale, it should not be a problem, but there are circumstances when it can be very troublesome.

Comment: If you run into problems with the "Valid Date" stuff, you can force them using `DateSerial`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx05d0c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Even though the control panel is set to proper Locale or Language, the developer might be from a completely different location handling projects from different nation.

It is nice to read different views from all experts. To override OS or Excel Intelligence from determining the date format, it is better to format it by using "=Text" command.